# When comparing oral infection v IV infection in mice, why would the CFU given be different volumes?

Tags: animal-models

In the paper, orally infected mice are given 1x10^9 CFU of C. Rodentium and IV infected mice are given 5x10^7 CFU of the pathogen. Does anyone know if there is a generic reason for this? Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 1):

**Intravenous delivery of pathogen produces infection more efficiently than transmucosal delivery.**

10^7 is 2 orders of magnitude less than 10^9.  It is not the volume that is different (although it may be), it is CFUs or "colony forming units" which is a proxy for viable pathogens in the inoculum.  The oral dose is 100x that of the IV.

Getting germs directly into the bloodstream bypasses the built in protections that our mucosal surfaces have.  The GI and GU tract have a lot of defenses.   For example an experimental SIV infection produced intravenously in monkeys requires an order of magnitude less virus than an infection established rectally or vaginally.

I would suspect that the CFUs of a given pathogen via a given route is something established empirically as producing the desired outcome.  If you used the same CFUs for an IV route as were required for the oral route, you might have a fair number of mice that just died from septic shock from the huge number of bacteria suddenly in the blood.  Given the 2 order of magnitude difference of inoculum (IV vs PO) to produce infection you might conclude that the stomach kills 99% of any inoculum.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful and makes sense!